# I'll get you some coffee vs I'll go get you some coffee

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, synonyms

ex.1: I'll get you some coffee.

ex.2: I'll go get you some coffee.

ex.3: I'll get some coffee to you (sounds natural to a native speaker?)

Do examples 1 and 2 mean the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

Ex. 1 suggests the coffee jug is close by.

Ex. 2 suggests you'll have to go and fetch some.

Ex. 3 suggests you'll place an order to get coffee delivered.

Answer (score 0):

If getting the coffee involves going somewhere --rather than just turning around and pouring coffee-- then the first two expressions are both correct and have the same meaning. The "go" part is understood in the first one. The first expression can also be used when you don't have to go somewhere to get the coffee.

The third expression isn't correct if you mean the same as expressions 1 and 2.

Comment: I could see "I'll get some coffee to you" being used to mean something like "I will have some coffee sent to you", although it doesn't mean the same as either of the first two sentences and is just less likely-sounding.

Comment: @stangdon Good catch. I've amended my answer